# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on post save or add media

Tags: posts, errors, save-post

About a year ago the site was moved to another host (same domain name). Every time I attempt to save a post, page or upload media, I'm immediately sent a connection reset error (This webpage is not available - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET), but admin-ajax.php is autosaving empty drafts and it is possible to save changes in the menu, for example. I'm trying to fix the problem during a months and tried a number of solutions. I have to edit the site by SQL database editor at the moment. Any fresh ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error in WordPress usually occurs when there is a server connection problem during the execution of a POST request, such as when saving a post or adding media. There can be many reasons behind this error, but here are some common solutions that can be tried:

1. Check for Plugin/Theme Conflicts - Start by deactivating all plugins and switching to a default theme.
2. Increase PHP Memory Limit - Insufficient PHP memory can sometimes cause connection reset errors
3. Check Server Logs - Check your server's error logs to see if there are any specific errors or issues reported at the time of the connection reset.
4. Disable Security Plugins: Certain security plugins might interfere with the POST request and cause connection reset errors.
5. Max Execution Time: If your server's max execution time is set too low, it could result in connection reset errors.

If none of the above works, then the problem may be related to your hosting provider. Contact their support team and explain the problem to see if they can provide additional information or fix the problem on their end.

Comment: Thank you.  You are right - none of above works. 1. Done 2. Increased to 256M 3. Nothing is there 4. All WP plugins were deactivated 5. max_execution_time=60 (Error appears in less than 1 sec). Could it be really on the hosting side? I could save menu by WP, change some settings and I was pretty sure it is on my side.

Comment: If you have tried all the steps mentioned before and the issue persists, it is possible that the problem lies on the hosting side. Some hosting providers have strict limitations and configurations that could affect the functioning of certain WordPress features.

To be sure about the cause of the issue, you can try Debugging. This will display any PHP errors or warnings that could be contributing to the problem.  

Also, temporarily switch to a default WordPress theme (e.g., Twenty Twenty-One) and try saving the menu again. This will rule out any issues related to your current theme.